# How to remove light coloured body in fullPage.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

In section one I want to remove this light coloured rectangle that you see so that whole screen is of one colour. How to do that.
https://jsfiddle.net/5z9ot3t1/

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">One</div>
    <div class="section">
       <div class="slide">Two 1</div>
       <div class="slide">Two 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">Three</div>
    <div class="section">Four</div>
</div>

$('#fullpage').fullpage({
   sectionsColor: ['yellow', 'orange', '#C0C0C0', '#ADD8E6'],
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear. Try to be more specific. Sine I can't comment, I will give you an answer to what I think that you're asking.

I will assume that with light colored rectangle in section one, what you really mean is the yellow background in section one. If so, you can get section one to have no background color by setting its parameter in the array to "none" or "transparent".

Like this:

```
sectionsColor: ['none', 'orange', '#C0C0C0', '#ADD8E6']
```

Comment: https://ibb.co/mcB2Un Can't you see light yellow box inside bigger dark yellow one. I want to remove that.

Comment: I do not see that lighter box as in your image. It's not in the code either. Could it be your monitor maybe? Try resizing the browser window and see what happens. Or what happens when you change to another color or remove the color?